# Windows Server - check remote access

Tags: windows-server-2003, remote-desktop, remote-access

I have to check account access to about 700 servers with Windows Server 2003.
We had access to all these servers, but over the years some of the servers changed owners and my group no longer have access to those servers. Now I have to check which servers we no longer suport.
The only method I know is to login via Remote Desktop, but there must be some way to do it automatically.
Could you tell me is there a way of simply checking access to server from any kind of programing language or script?

Answer (score 0):

I Suggest you check out [this link.](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Connect-Mstsc-Open-RDP-2064b10b) I would think it will give an error that you can catch when the connection fails.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to kick it old school, you can do this with a list of servers (dumped from AD?) and batch.

```
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%s in (servers.txt) do (
sc \\%%s query "W32Time" | findstr /c:"FAILED"
if errorlevel 1 echo %%s >> access.txt
)

for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (servers.txt) do (
find "%%a" < access.txt > nul
if errorlevel 1 echo %%a >> accessdenied.txt
)
```

There are probably easy ways to do it in other languages, too, but I had that one lying around.

You may have to tweak the service and the error string for your environment.